# Android EditText causing scroll

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView which contains 3 "pages". When my app starts up, I tell the scrollview to scroll one screen width so that the middle page is always displayed first. See below:

```
+------+------+------+
+  ET  +      +      +
+------+      +      +
+      +      +      +
+      +      +      +
+------+------+------+
       ^      ^
```

ET above represents an EditText view. If I don't add the EditText so the first page, it behaves fine. However, if I add the EditText view, the scroll view always scrolls to the left page and displays the keyboard on my phone.

Why does the EditText view (or keyboard??) cause the scrollview to scroll to the far left? How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: can you post some relevant code? Activity file and xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can post the code it will be better.

But so far what you have to do is to set the focus on your main `ScrollView` and clear the focus from your `EditText`

Comment: I am more than happy to post some of the code but it will take time to gut out the relevant bits or make a simple example. By the sounds of things I should be calling setFocusable(false) on the EdtText? I'll give that a try..

Comment: Indeed, setFocusable(false) has the desired effect. Thank you. I guess now I just need to call setFocusable(true) once I scroll to that page so that editing can take place.